# What can I use lava for?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have a river of lava near my base, and I'm not sure what I can do with it. What can I do with lava in Minecraft Pocket Edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it as a mob killing trap. Hostile mobs go towards you, so you can have lava between the both of you. A cool thing to do is to make sort of a lava-fall. It's like a waterfall, but with lava. Finally, a very useful design would be to dig very deep, so the lava could sink in and build a bridge over it.

Comment: This question is asking about the Pocket Edition, not the PC version. Please edit your answer so that it fits this.

Comment: @DanielPalamarchuk I have rolled back your tag edits, as they are not appropriate for these questions.  Minecraft and Minecraft:PE are two separate games.  Please familiarize yourself with how tagging is used here before doing any further retagging.